# java student gpa files and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file

can someone help me with this codes.

This is the file

```
57363 Joy  Ryder    D D C P H H C D

72992 Laura Norder  H H H D D H H H

71258 Eileen Over   C F C D C C C P
```

I am trying to store the ID in array which is the 5 digits and convert the character to numbers and calculate the average gpa where `H=7`, `D=6`, `C=6`,`P=4`,`F=0` and store this in second array. And then sort this two arrary to largest to smallest value and write these value in output text file. This is my code so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGPA_17396934Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    String fileName;
    char grade[] = new char[8];
    File myfile;
    int num = 0;

    do{
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");
    fileName = kb.next();

    myfile = new File(fileName);
    if (myfile.exists()) {
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(myfile);
        while (infile.hasNext()) {

            int ID = infile.nextInt();
            String name = infile.next();
            String surname = infile.next();

            // it is converting the characters to numbers but not reading all characters
            also how do I get average of this numbers and store in appropriate array 
            also how to store ID in array
            for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
                grade[i] = infile.next().charAt(0);

            if (grade[i] == 'H')
            num = 7;
            else if (grade[i] == 'D')
            num = 6;
            else if (grade[i] == 'C')
            num = 5;
            else if (grade[i] == 'P')
            num = 4;
            else if (grade[i] == 'F')
            num = 0;
            }

            System.out.println(ID + "\t" +name + "\t" +surname + "\t" + num);


        }

    }
    else{

        System.out.println("file not found...");
    }
    }while(!myfile.exists());

}

}
```

and my output is

```
Enter the name of the file: 
grades

57363   Joy Ryder   6

72992   Laura   Norder  7

71258   Eileen  Over  4
```

Comment: what is troubling you ? what is the issue? if it is your homework, nobody will do that for you :)

Comment: i am not sure how to store id and grades into arrays and write in files

Comment: so you know your issues. first how to store in the array, and second how to write in file. So try to google them and learn them. if you are stuck in some place, let's us know. you must learn how to research

Comment: i have been trying since one week but no luck so far.. i am not able to understand at all

Comment: Just change your post fast, say which part you have trouble so we can explain and help you to understand :)

Comment: click on edit and ask what is troubling you so other can explain to you

Comment: the problem here is converting those 8 characters to numbers and find average gpa and storing ID and average gpa in appropriate arrays and display in file..

Comment: you have done the converting right, you need to define another array and save those num inside that array

Comment: thats the part I am stuck on.. I dont know how to do that

Comment: i know the basics of array but i am not sure how to use array in this specific questions.. example regarding this question would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Let's do an example as your blue print so you can follow and learn

As you know, you need an `array`

lets see what `array` is in `Java`?

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of
>   a single type
>
> **1**. It has a length which means you can save certain amount of data in side it
>
> **2**. The type of object has to be same

[image]

Let's see how to define an `array` in `Java`

```
dataType[] arrayRefVar ;
```

for example :  `int[] arryInt;`

Creating array in Java

```
arrayRefVar = new dataType[arraySize];
```

for example `arrayInt = new int[5];`

How to assign a value to each index of array

for example `arrayInt[2] = 23;`

If you want to use for loop to populate your array you can do as follows

```
 for(int i =0; i < arrayInt.length ; i++){
        arrayInt[i] = i ;
        System.out.print(" " + i);
 }
```

output: `0 1 2 3 4`

**Note**: array index starts from zero in Java